# vsconsole.exe not working within PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to rum my test cases through Visual Studio test in PowerShell but it's giving me an error. It's working fine with CMD - why?

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"  C:\DLL\Automation_2.dll /Tests:AccessToWire
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prefix your invoke with an ampersand. Also use quotes for your parameters:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"  "C:\DLL\Automation_2.dll" "/Tests:AccessToWire"
```